# Using MySQL UPDATE statement in Wordpress Php file

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have 1 field to update in Mysql database

```
table -> wp_usermeta

field -> meta_key: _ywpar_user_total_points

field -> meta_value: 4000
```

The update statement: UPDATE

```
wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value`= 15 WHERE `user_id`= 1 and `meta_key`="_ywpar_user_total_points"
```

I've already tried a bunch of code from Wordpress codex and Youtube and others website, like:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query
("
    UPDATE $wpdb->wp_usermeta
    SET meta_value = 7000
    WHERE user_id = 1
        AND meta_key = '_ywpar_user_total_points'
");
```

---

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 
    'wp_usermeta', 
    array( 
        'meta_value' => 4000,
    ),
    array( 
        'meta_key' => '_ywpar_user_total_points', 'user_id' => 1
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```

---

none of them are working

Comment: Where you are passing value of %d and %s in second query? have you tried to display query first?

Comment: that the format that i copy from wordpress codex,
I'm not really know how to use that value, so I just leave it there.  
If i'm doing it wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user6582353 Here https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb is the ref.and syntax about how update work. see its syntax and understand it

```
$wpdb->update( 
    'table', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1',  // string
        'column2' => 'value2'   // integer (number) 
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => 1 ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```

Here %s is used for column1 value format which we are passing as string so provided %s and second column2 will be an integer type data so here taken %d.same way for where format too, in where passed only ID of integer type so provided %d only as last argument in array

Consider your case now

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->update( 
    'wp_usermeta', 
    array( 
        'meta_value' => 4000,
    ),
    array( 
        'meta_key' => '_ywpar_user_total_points', 'user_id' => 1
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',   // value1
        '%d'    // value2
    ), 
    array( '%d' ) 
);
```

So here you are changing only 1 value which is integer and the second is where format where you are taking 2 arguments 1 is of string and second is of integer so the final syntax would be something like

```
 global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update( 
        'wp_usermeta', 
        array( 
            'meta_value' => 4000,
        ),
        array( 
            'meta_key' => '_ywpar_user_total_points', 'user_id' => 1
        ), 
        array( 
            '%d'     // for meta_value
        ), 
        array( 
            '%s',   // for meta_key
            '%d'    // for user_id
        ) 
    );
```

Hope its clear to you now and works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use inbuilt function for this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use update user meta function i hope this will solve your problem.
[Click here for more details about update_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)

```
update_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, false)
```

Comment: still not working, I'm not sure if the format i'm filling is corrected or not

Comment: **`update_user_meta(1, 'meta_value', 4000, false)?** this is the wrong way to update the meta first argument of this function is user id, second argument is meta_key third is for value @user